# Is there modern chess software similar to ChessMaster series?

Tags: software, chessmaster

I'm interested in a software for a middle-casual player.

It should have learning tools, rich graphics with modern screens support and some entertainment features, similar to ChessMaster. Chessmaster is good but seems to be outdated.

Applications like Fritz are too heavy and UI has always been a second class citizen for them.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [LucasChess](http://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/) . It has a lot of interesting learning tools (i.e. Play like a Grandmaster) ,  40 (!!!) engines from 0 to 3300 ELO and a really nice UI. It is free and is actively developed.