# Chessmaster: Modern version of lectures?

Tags: software, reference-request, chessmaster, waitzkin

**Thing 1**: This [lichess study](https://lichess.org/study/Dhtqm1My) says

> Examining positions from Josh Waitzkin's academy, Larry Christiansen's attacking chess, and other exercises or games from this (now) ancient chess program in light of recent advances.

I assume this isn't talking about the chessmaster engine/s but about the lectures specifically. If not, then forget this part.

**Thing 2**: I recall I played chessmaster 1st as a kid 2 decades ago in 2000/2001 when my [dad](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33844/difference-between-chess-puzzle-and-chess-problem-in-this-episode-of-the-queens) introduced me and then again around 1 decade ago in 2010/2011 when I wanted to [beat my cousin](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/chess/sibling-rivalry-got-magnus-carlsen-started/articleshow/25662753.cms) and again this year 2020/2021 when I got back into chess/9LX for the 2nd time (see my previous questions if you want: [1](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34048/josh-waitzkin-chessmaster-mastery-quiz-order-of-check-vs-trade), [2](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34038/josh-waitzkin-on-trading-pieces-the-art-of-the-trade), [3](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34055/josh-waitzkin-chessmaster-mastery-quiz-spatial-advantage-trading-bishops)). I kinda just assumed it was the standard thing people go to when they learn chess(/chess960).

**Question**: Nowadays, do people still use chessmaster as much? I mean, are the chessmaster **lectures still good, *relative* to possibly a lot more modern teaching materials, and if not, then what modern series of lectures do people learn the stuff** in the chessmaster series (**no books** please. just online courses or video lectures like on chessable or youtube) ? For example, Josh Waitzkin has all these series on strategy, [endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/whats-next-after-josh-waitzkins-endgame-series-in-chessmaster), the art of learning, psychology of competition, etc.

- [This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19342/is-there-modern-chess-software-similar-to-chessmaster-series) says chessmaster 'seems to be outdated'. (I guess this refers not to the engine but really to the learning and stuff.)

---

**A discussion from 2014 reddit thread** [Is Chessmaster dead? What is the current leading chess software for PC (Windows)?](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/25c9f8/is_chessmaster_dead_what_is_the_current_leading/) (It's not clear if the question is asking about the lectures or about the engine):

> The course by Josh Waitzkin is still IMO one of the better ways to learn chess alone.

and then

> I really, really liked the Waitzkin stuff on CMX, but honestly, there's gobs of awesome material on YouTube these days. Check the St. Louis Chess Club Channel. That'll keep you busy for a year.

---

Related? [How did chess change over the 2010s and should I keep anything in mind for buying books from before 2010?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/how-did-chess-change-over-the-2010s-and-should-i-keep-anything-in-mind-for-buyin)

Comment: What does it mean for a lecture to be "good"? I'm afraid that's quite subjective as different people will have different metrics to evaluate their quality

Comment: @David Good question...well...do people still use it? or do people use something else?

Comment: @David actually there's the qualifier 'still'. i mean to ask if chessmaster is not outdated or something. idk i just assumed that before chessmaster was like the standard thing people go to to learn chess and then now chessmaster's been replaced by youtube or some other software (for learning about chess/chess960, not for analysing games. so i really mean the chessmaster lectures not the chessmaster engine or whatever)

Comment: @David my initial question was 'Are the chessmaster lectures (insert antonym of outdated)?' but then post was closed. then the question went through many revisions. any specific suggestions for improvement please? Edit: I edited question to hopefully be clearer

Comment: It's not a matter of how you formulate the question, but rather the "thing you want to know" itself. chessmaster was definitely not "standard" and in fact this is the first time I hear of it and I don't know anyone who used it as a main resource for chess training/knowledge

Comment: The fundamentals are never outdated. Maybe there is a meta at the highest level using engine lines.

Comment: @qwr hooray! :D post as answer?